# Ipopt error: malloc(): invalid size (unsorted) Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: c++, valgrind, ipopt

I'm working with Ipopt C++ library (https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt).

Planning to work on optimization of trajectories soon, but for now I'm practicing on the simple tasks.

In particular I've been trying to solve this:

```
Find a set of N points on the 2D plane such that:
• the first and last point are positioned at (0, 0) and (10, 10), respectively;
• the distances between two consecutive points are equal;
• there is no point lying on a circle or radius 1 centered at (4, 4);
• the sum of the distances between consecutive points is minimized.
```

I wrote C++ code for finding the solution. It creates cvs file with optimized points.

```
#include "Ipopt/src/Interfaces/IpIpoptApplication.hpp"
#include "Ipopt/src/Interfaces/IpTNLP.hpp"
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream> // Include for file operations

using namespace Ipopt;

class PointSetProblem : public TNLP {
public:
    // Constructor
    PointSetProblem(int N, double distance, const std::vector<double>& obstacle, const std::vector<double>& pinit, const std::vector<double>& pfin)
        : N_(N), distance_(distance), obstacle_(obstacle), pinit_(pinit), pfin_(pfin) {}

    int getN() const {
        return N_;
    }

    // Define problem dimensions
    virtual bool get_nlp_info(Index& n, Index& m, Index& nnz_jac_g, Index& nnz_h_lag, IndexStyleEnum& index_style) {
        // Number of variables (2D coordinates for N points)
        n = 2 * N_;

        // Number of equality constraints (N-1 distances between points)
        m = N_ - 1;

        // Number of non-zero elements in the Jacobian of the constraints
        nnz_jac_g = 2 * (N_ - 1);

        // Number of non-zero elements in the Hessian of the Lagrangian (0 if not available)
        nnz_h_lag = 0;

        // Use C-style indexing
        index_style = TNLP::C_STYLE;
        return true;
    }

    // Define bounds for variables and constraints
    virtual bool get_bounds_info(Index n, Number* x_l, Number* x_u, Index m, Number* g_l, Number* g_u) {
    // Variable bounds (all points are in [0, 10] x [0, 10])
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            x_l[2 * i] = 0.0;   // x coordinate
            x_l[2 * i + 1] = 0.0; // y coordinate
            x_u[2 * i] = 10.0;   // x coordinate
            x_u[2 * i + 1] = 10.0; // y coordinate
        }

        // Constraint bounds (distances between points)
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
            g_l[i] = 0.0; // Lower bound for distances
            g_u[i] = distance_; // Upper bound for distances
        }

        // Add constraints to avoid the circle of radius 1 centered at (4, 4)
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            double dx = x_l[2 * i] - obstacle_[0];
            double dy = x_l[2 * i + 1] - obstacle_[1];
            double distance_squared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
            g_l[N_ - 1 + i] = -1e20; // Ensure points are outside the circle
            g_u[N_ - 1 + i] = 1e20; // A large upper bound to ensure the circle constraint is not violated
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Define initial guess for the variables
    virtual bool get_starting_point(Index n, bool init_x, Number* x, bool init_z, Number* z_L, Number* z_U, Index m, bool init_lambda, Number* lambda) {
        // Initialize points with equally spaced distances
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            x[2 * i] = pinit_[0] + (pfin_[0] - pinit_[0]) * i / (N_ - 1);
            x[2 * i + 1] = pinit_[1] + (pfin_[1] - pinit_[1]) * i / (N_ - 1);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Define the objective function
    virtual bool eval_f(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Number& obj_value) {
        // Minimize the sum of distances between consecutive points
        obj_value = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
            double dx = x[2 * (i + 1)] - x[2 * i];
            double dy = x[2 * (i + 1) + 1] - x[2 * i + 1];
            obj_value += std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Define the constraints
    virtual bool eval_g(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Index m, Number* g) {
        // Calculate distances between consecutive points and use them as constraints
        for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
            double dx = x[2 * (i + 1)] - x[2 * i];
            double dy = x[2 * (i + 1) + 1] - x[2 * i + 1];
            g[i] = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Define the Jacobian of the constraints
    virtual bool eval_jac_g(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Index m, Index nele_jac, Index* iRow, Index* jCol, Number* values) {
        // Structure of the Jacobian matrix
        if (values == NULL) {
            for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
                iRow[2 * i] = i;
                jCol[2 * i] = 2 * i;
                iRow[2 * i + 1] = i;
                jCol[2 * i + 1] = 2 * i + 1;
            }
        } else {
            // Calculate the values of the Jacobian matrix
            for (int i = 0; i < N_ - 1; i++) {
                double dx = x[2 * (i + 1)] - x[2 * i];
                double dy = x[2 * (i + 1) + 1] - x[2 * i + 1];
                double dist = std::sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                values[2 * i] = dx / dist;
                values[2 * i + 1] = dy / dist;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Define the gradient of the objective function
    virtual bool eval_grad_f(Index n, const Number* x, bool new_x, Number* grad_f) {
        // Implement the gradient evaluation
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            grad_f[2 * i] = 0.0; // Gradient of the x-coordinate
            grad_f[2 * i + 1] = 0.0; // Gradient of the y-coordinate
        }
        return true;
    }

    // Method to finalize the solution
    virtual void finalize_solution(
        Ipopt::SolverReturn status, // Change this type to Ipopt::SolverReturn
        Ipopt::Index n,
        const Ipopt::Number* x,
        const Ipopt::Number* z_L,
        const Ipopt::Number* z_U,
        Ipopt::Index m,
        const Ipopt::Number* g,
        const Ipopt::Number* lambda,
        Ipopt::Number obj_value,
        const Ipopt::IpoptData* ip_data,
        Ipopt::IpoptCalculatedQuantities* ip_cq
    ) {
        if (status == Ipopt::SUCCESS) { // Change this comparison to Ipopt::SUCCESS
            // Write the optimal points to a CSV file
            std::ofstream outFile("optimal_points.csv");
            for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
                outFile << x[2 * i] << "," << x[2 * i + 1] << std::endl;
            }
            outFile.close();
            std::cout << "Optimal points saved to 'optimal_points.csv'." << std::endl;
        }
    }

private:
    int N_; // Number of points
    double distance_; // Constraint distance
    std::vector<double> obstacle_; // Obstacle position
    std::vector<double> pinit_; // Initial point
    std::vector<double> pfin_; // Final point
};

int main() {
    int N = 30; // Number of points
    double distance = 2; // Constraint distance
    std::vector<double> obstacle = {4.0, 4.0};
    std::vector<double> pinit = {0.0, 0.0};
    std::vector<double> pfin = {10.0, 10.0};

    SmartPtr<TNLP> pointSetProblem = new PointSetProblem(N, distance, obstacle, pinit, pfin);
    SmartPtr<IpoptApplication> app = IpoptApplicationFactory();

    // Set the Hessian approximation method to limited-memory
    app->Options()->SetStringValue("hessian_approximation", "limited-memory");

    app->RethrowNonIpoptException(true);
    ApplicationReturnStatus status = app->Initialize();
    if (status != Solve_Succeeded) {
        std::cout << "IPOPT initialization failed!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    status = app->OptimizeTNLP(pointSetProblem);

    if (status == Solve_Succeeded || status == Solved_To_Acceptable_Level) {
        Number obj_value;
        Number x[2 * N];
        pointSetProblem->eval_f(2 * N, x, true, obj_value);

        std::cout << "Optimal points:" << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            std::cout << "Point " << i + 1 << ": (" << x[2 * i] << ", " << x[2 * i + 1] << ")" << std::endl;
        }
        std::cout << "Optimal Objective Value: " << obj_value << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "IPOPT optimization failed with status " << status << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that my code satisfies all the required tasks except for this one:

`• there is no point lying on a circle or radius 1 centered at (4, 4);`

That's why I added this part of the code for creating some obstacle:

```
// Add constraints to avoid the circle of radius 1 centered at (4, 4)
        for (int i = 0; i < N_; i++) {
            double dx = x_l[2 * i] - obstacle_[0];
            double dy = x_l[2 * i + 1] - obstacle_[1];
            double distance_squared = dx * dx + dy * dy;
            g_l[N_ - 1 + i] = -1e20; // Ensure points are outside the circle
            g_u[N_ - 1 + i] = 1e20; // A large upper bound to ensure the circle constraint is not violated
    }
```

And the thing is that when the last two lines are commented out :

```
g_l[N_ - 1 + i] = -1e20; 
g_u[N_ - 1 + i] = 1e20;
```

the code can be compiled but it doesn't affect the location of the points (because I didn't give the upper and lower bounds) But when they are not commented out it can be compiled again but when I run the program the Ipopt library gives the following error:

`******************************************************************************
This program contains Ipopt, a library for large-scale nonlinear optimization.
Ipopt is released as open source code under the Eclipse Public License (EPL).
For more information visit https://github.com/coin-or/Ipopt

---

This is Ipopt version 3.14.13, running with linear solver MUMPS 5.6.0.
malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
Aborted (core dumped)`

What can be the problem? Why should I do? Thank you for your time in advance!

I tried to change the upper and lower bounds changing the values. However it didn't help.

Here is a plot: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5eF4.png)

Update after debugging symbols enabled

```
==20895== Invalid write of size 8
==20895==    at 0x10B073: PointSetProblem::get_bounds_info(int, double*, double*, int, double*, double*) (tr_smlk_try_ccrcle.cpp:67)
==20895==    by 0x4A53B95: Ipopt::TNLPAdapter::GetSpaces(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::SymMatrixSpace const>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49D14AE: Ipopt::OrigIpoptNLP::InitializeStructures(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49A5DAA: Ipopt::IpoptData::InitializeDataStructures(Ipopt::IpoptNLP&, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x495C9E7: Ipopt::DefaultIterateInitializer::SetInitialIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975387: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::InitializeIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975522: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::Optimize(bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A396BB: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::call_optimize() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A3BA07: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::AlgorithmBuilder>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A352CC: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A373BD: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeTNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::TNLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x10A632: main (tr_smlk_try_ccrcle.cpp:193)
==20895==  Address 0x608fd88 is 0 bytes after a block of size 232 alloc'd
==20895==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20895==    by 0x4A53B38: Ipopt::TNLPAdapter::GetSpaces(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::SymMatrixSpace const>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49D14AE: Ipopt::OrigIpoptNLP::InitializeStructures(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49A5DAA: Ipopt::IpoptData::InitializeDataStructures(Ipopt::IpoptNLP&, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x495C9E7: Ipopt::DefaultIterateInitializer::SetInitialIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975387: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::InitializeIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975522: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::Optimize(bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A396BB: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::call_optimize() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A3BA07: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::AlgorithmBuilder>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A352CC: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A373BD: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeTNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::TNLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x10A632: main (tr_smlk_try_ccrcle.cpp:193)
==20895== 
==20895== Invalid write of size 8
==20895==    at 0x10B09F: PointSetProblem::get_bounds_info(int, double*, double*, int, double*, double*) (tr_smlk_try_ccrcle.cpp:68)
==20895==    by 0x4A53B95: Ipopt::TNLPAdapter::GetSpaces(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::SymMatrixSpace const>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49D14AE: Ipopt::OrigIpoptNLP::InitializeStructures(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49A5DAA: Ipopt::IpoptData::InitializeDataStructures(Ipopt::IpoptNLP&, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x495C9E7: Ipopt::DefaultIterateInitializer::SetInitialIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975387: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::InitializeIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975522: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::Optimize(bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A396BB: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::call_optimize() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A3BA07: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::AlgorithmBuilder>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A352CC: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A373BD: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeTNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::TNLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x10A632: main (tr_smlk_try_ccrcle.cpp:193)
==20895==  Address 0x608feb8 is 0 bytes after a block of size 232 alloc'd
==20895==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20895==    by 0x4A53B62: Ipopt::TNLPAdapter::GetSpaces(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::SymMatrixSpace const>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49D14AE: Ipopt::OrigIpoptNLP::InitializeStructures(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49A5DAA: Ipopt::IpoptData::InitializeDataStructures(Ipopt::IpoptNLP&, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x495C9E7: Ipopt::DefaultIterateInitializer::SetInitialIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975387: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::InitializeIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975522: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::Optimize(bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A396BB: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::call_optimize() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A3BA07: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::AlgorithmBuilder>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A352CC: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A373BD: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeTNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::TNLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x10A632: main (tr_smlk_try_ccrcle.cpp:193)
==20895== 
--20895-- VALGRIND INTERNAL ERROR: Valgrind received a signal 7 (SIGBUS) - exiting
--20895-- si_code=128;  Faulting address: 0x0;  sp: 0x1002ca9e40

valgrind: the 'impossible' happened:
   Killed by fatal signal

host stacktrace:
==20895==    at 0x5805160F: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==20895==    by 0x58005EB7: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==20895==    by 0x580A7204: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)
==20895==    by 0x580F5FD4: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux)

sched status:
  running_tid=1

Thread 1: status = VgTs_Runnable (lwpid 20895)
==20895==    at 0x483C583: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20895==    by 0x4A53BC2: Ipopt::TNLPAdapter::GetSpaces(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::VectorSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::MatrixSpace const>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::SymMatrixSpace const>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49D14AE: Ipopt::OrigIpoptNLP::InitializeStructures(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, bool, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::Vector>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x49A5DAA: Ipopt::IpoptData::InitializeDataStructures(Ipopt::IpoptNLP&, bool, bool, bool, bool, bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x495C9E7: Ipopt::DefaultIterateInitializer::SetInitialIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975387: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::InitializeIterates() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4975522: Ipopt::IpoptAlgorithm::Optimize(bool) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A396BB: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::call_optimize() (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A3BA07: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&, Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::AlgorithmBuilder>&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A352CC: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::NLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x4A373BD: Ipopt::IpoptApplication::OptimizeTNLP(Ipopt::SmartPtr<Ipopt::TNLP> const&) (in /local/vol00/home/vpetrov/dev/optimization/ipopt/Ipopt/src/.libs/libipopt.so.3.14.13)
==20895==    by 0x10A632: main (tr_smlk_try_ccrcle.cpp:193)
client stack range: [0x1FFEFFC000 0x1FFF000FFF] client SP: 0x1FFEFFEB30
valgrind stack range: [0x1002BAA000 0x1002CA9FFF] top usage: 18696 of 1048576
```

Comment: The message from `malloc()` is that the heap is corrupted. This is usually caused by writing out-of-bounds. Any indexing where the index is computed as `2 * i` or `2 * i + 1` is a suspect.

Comment: I played with the indexes a little bit but I still have troubles with this error: malloc(): invalid size (unsorted)
Aborted (core dumped)

Comment: `valgrind` will tell you where exactly the problem is.

Comment: I used :
valgrind --leak-check=full ./tr_smlk_crcl
the valgrind showed: Invalid write of size 8

What should I change in the code?

Comment: You need to locate the exact spot in `get_bounds_info` where the invalid write is happening. If `valgrind` doesn’t give any further details, it may be the case that debugging symbols are unavailable. Try to build it with `-g` or even `-O0 -g`. Then `valgrind` should print out the exact line where the invalid write occurred.

Comment: enabled the debugging symbols, updated the issue. the valgrind points at (tr_smlk_try_ccrcle.cpp:67) essentially at this line : g_l[N_ - 1 + i] = -1e20; // Ensure points are outside the circle

Comment: That’s a good start. The obvious next step is to print out out what the call site of `get_bounds_info` passes in, how big the `g_l` array is, what `N_` is, what `N_ - 1 + i` evaluates to in the loop etc. It may well be the case that `g_l` is not big enough for an offset of `2 * N_ - 2`, which occurs when `i == N_ - 1`. But we don’t see in your code snippet where and how `g_l` is allocated.

Comment: Oh thank you very much, the problem was solved. I had N_-1 array size, and tried to write to N_ - 1 + i. I appreciate your help!